# Using VMware .dmvk file with VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-player

My OS#1 is Windows 7 64bit, I have installed *VMware Player* and have installed Windows XP as my Guest OS.

[image]

I Plan to install Ubuntu 64bit on another *harddisk's partition* as OS#2.

Is it possible to use *VirtualBox* on Ubuntu to open exising **.dmvk** file, doing some works, and later time back to open with *VMware Player* when booting to Windows 7?

If possible, please guide some brief instructions how to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the disk image both on VirtualBox and VMware alternately as long as you shutdown your virtual machine every time you want to switch, and possibly you will have to create a new configuration each time you made some major changes related to virtual hardware (e.g. resize disk image). Those programs they keep a session file to keep track of what you have done with your virtual machine so that the next time you power or wake it up, it knows where to start from.

In VirtualBox you can create a new virtual machine and load an existing image disk. I think it's quite clear how to do it, the UI is pretty usable. Same as in VMWare.